# Why does C#'s base types' Equals implementation casts twice?

Tags: c#, performance

I've been looking at the Reference Source for .NET and the implementation of Equals for `Int32`, for instance, looks like this:

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj is Int32)) {
        return false;
    }
    return m_value == ((Int32)obj).m_value;
}
```

I've looked up for Char and Bool, and they both do the same thing.

Source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/13ad4f778352f7c4.html

This, however, violates `CA1800: Do not cast unnecessarily`.

Also, I've done some simple tests with `is` vs creating a local variable, and the latter seems to always yield better performance. Does this somehow not apply to basic types? And, if not, isn't it right to assume that, since this is a basic method, it may be called millions of times in an algorithm and thus performance should be top priority?

Comment: How would you cast a non-nullable primitive only once, without incurring a cost of potential exception?

Comment: Were your tests with a `struct` or a `class`?

Comment: @juharr The tests were with an int, just like the example I posted. @PatrykĆwiek is right though, I wasn't remembering the fact that casting with `(int)` can throw an exception.

Comment: In general the alternative code uses `as` and null checking, but for value types that requires using `T?`, which is probably slower than first checking and then casting. The `as` based variant is often used when implementing equality for reference types.

Comment: @downvoter, please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you just cast the value without any defensive code:

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj)
{
     return m_value == ((Int32)obj).m_value;
}
```

Since `Equals` can take an `object`, we should be able not only to pass in `int` values, but also, `float`, `string`, or practically any type. Even worse, the compiler won't complain, because, in fact, they are all just `objects` anyway, so the call is completely legal.

But what happens if you cast a `string` to an `int`? We get an `InvalidCastException` at runtime, which is not nice at all.

Therefore, we have to check that the `object` is actually an `int`, before casting it to an `int`, that's what the `is` keyword does after all.

As a side note, the method body could have also be written as:

```
return obj is Int32 ? m_value == ((Int32)obj).m_value : false;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your alternative implementation should count as a *simplification*.

Comment: @CodesInChaos You're right, I changed my expression

Comment: @MatiasCicero Yea, you're totally right, I didn't notice that when I first looked at the source code. Thanks for the fast answer, can't even accept it yet :)

Comment: @andre_ss6 No problem! :)

Comment: technically you'd have to do a `try-catch` to get the same functionality and that's the part that's "not nice".

Comment: An even simpler one-liner for that method is `return obj is Int32 && m_value == ((Int32) obj).m_value;`  No need for a ternary, the short-circuiting behavior of the `&&` operator takes care of everything..

Answer (score 0):

The `is` operator is used to check the type of the `obj`.
A direct cast may result in an Exception if the `obj` is not of the same type to which you cast it (Int32 in this case).
To prevent this potential exception, `is` is used.
Cases when `obj` is of a different type are directly jumped by this approach.

Comment: Otherwise you can cast in a try block, if an exception is caught return false

Comment: Using exceptions for stuff that is to be expected (and can be handled differently) is wrong. Also, in case of an exception, performance of `try...catch` is far worse than checking `is`.

Comment: I too agree to it, but I provided the alternative for those who don't agree